# События! Как грамотно подписаться/отписаться?

Tags: c#

У меня возникли воросы на который я, к сожалению, не нашел однозначного ответа.

Есть два класса `A` , `B` . У класса B есть `public ObservableCollection` , у которого есть событие `CollectionChanged` .

Я подисываюсь на данное событие из класса `A` и `B` .

```
B.ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += Hello;

this.ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += Hello1;
```

Воспросы:

1. Как грамотно отписать **всех подписок** в классе `A` от события?
2. Как грамотно отписать **всех подписок** в классе `B` от события?
3. Почему считается плохим тоном отписываться так: `CollectionChanged = null` ? Что произойдет?

Comment: 3. Это разве сработает?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я незнаю, потому и спрашиваю, что произойдет. :) Я пологаю John дал ответ на это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала нужно чётко понимать, как работают события и делегаты. Когда вы подписываетесь, то передаёте событию делегат на метод, который он будет впоследствии вызывать. То есть связь однонаправленная `classA -> eventA -> delegateB -> сlassB` и в результате из класса B мы не можем знать, подписано что-то на него или нет.

1) Для подписки/отписки от события между разными экземплярам классов есть множество путей и у каждого свои плюсы и минусы. [Вот почитайте про события подробнее.](https://habr.com/post/89529/) Расписывать здесь не вижу смысла, но прочитать эту статью рекомендую.

2) Если происходит подписка метода на событие одного экземпляра класса, то отписывать не нужно. Так как в результате у вас событие будет вести на тот же класс и сборщик мусора, если не имеется других ссылок на этот класс, удалит его.

3) От события можно отписывать сразу всех через присвоение null, проблема лишь в том, что это возможно только из класса, которому это событие принадлежит. Для всех других классов доступно лишь два метода Add и Remove, то есть подписка (добавления делегата) и отписка (удаление делегата). В вашем случае у вас присвоить null не получится, так как CollectionChanged принадлежит ObservableCollection, к которому изнутри у вас нет доступа.

Comment: Только схема вверху не совсем к моему случаю, верно? В моем примере у класса A нет события и у класса B тоже. Как я понимаю событие есть только у ObservableCollection. Схема - это общее представление?

Comment: Прочитал статью, не все понял в силу неопытности в C#, но будк разбираться. Чего я не понял так это того, что в моем примере в классе `A` и `B` . Я смогу сразу отписаться от _всех подпищиков_ в каких бы классах они не были организованны? Т.е. допустим при отписке из клааса `A` я увижу, что подписан метод класса `A` и метод класса `B` ? И тоже самое я увижу при отписке в классе `B` ?

Comment: @Kirill В вашем случае сразу от всех отписаться не сможете. И узнать, кто подписан тоже. Полный доступ к событию имеет только класс-родитель, то есть ObservableCollection. Можно только подписаться и отписаться. Поэтому если нет возможности напрямую отписаться от события, то используйте методы в статье (слабые ссылки, менеджеры и т.д.).

Comment: @Kirill Но не забывайте, что всё это нужно только в случае, если коллекция живёт дольше, чем классы A или B. Если у вас коллекция временная и после работы с ней удаляются все ссылки на B или удаляется ссылка из B на коллекцию, то ничего отписывать не нужно.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо! И последний вопрос. Получается, что если нет возможности из др. класса проверить подписан ли определенный метод на событие, то возникнет ли исключение, если просто принудительно отписывать метод, если в данный момент он не был подписан на событие, как в моем примере? Если да, то как тогда лучше поступать?

Comment: @Kirill Такое можно и без вопроса самому попробовать) Исключений не будет, если не было до этого подписан метод, то при отписке просто вхолостую прогонится.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто писал на тот момент  с компьютера где нет VS, а ответ хотелось знать. :)

Answer (score 4):

Если ссылок на объект к которому мы подписались больше нет, то объект будет собран сборщиком мусора => отписка произойдет автоматически=> беспокоится в этом случае не нужно.

Однако, если у вас долгоживущие объекты и в определенным периоды вы хотите слушать, а в какие-то нет, то отписывайтесь явно.

Comment: Это точно? Подписчик не хранит ссылку на объект?

Comment: Я думаю, что да. А зачем подписчику хранить ссылку на издателя? Издатель хранит адреса функций, которые должен вызвать при наступлении события.

Comment: Ну да, согласен, там связь обратная, тот кто предоставляет события, хранит ссылки на подписчиков (точнее делегат хранит ссылку на класс, в котором он определен)